# object.jquery attribute

Tags: jquery

what does this code performs?

```
if(object.jquery){
  ....
}
```

I don't know what jQuery attribute does. I think it checks if 'object' is a valid jQuery object, but I'm not really sure.

Thanks in advance.

Esteve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's checking if `object` has a property called `jquery`, so yes it's checking if `object` is specifically a jquery object :)

It's **not** checking if it's been loaded (try it on this very page), that would be `if(window.jQuery)`, but jquery objects have a property called `jquery` which is the version, for example:

```
$().jquery //on this page, as of now (when answered): "1.3.2"
```